# A general way to make Lined Background independent to papersize/orientation

Tags: tikz-pgf, paper-size

I have the  following setup which generate lined-paper background in a4paper (modified from texblog and answer from this site)

I would like to make this code more papersize independent.

The value "28" on for-loop works for this papersize (A4), but  for other papersize or orientation (Landscape/Potrait), it need to be adjusted.

I'm guessing I can put \paperheight somewhere in the for-loop, but I don't know how to  convert  that value (which is in inch or cm) into (coordinate-unit) after \draw.

Or maybe doing arithmetic with `page.north west` and `page.south west`, if that even possible.

Yes I know,  I could just modified them manually (changing value 28 to 38 in for-loop when working in a3paper), but I'm interested on more automatic solution.

In short: **I have those many `\usepackage{geometry}` commented in code, and would want to make a single `\mygraphpaper` definition that works on them all.**

Layout document that I want to achieve:  No left/right margin, the same `x` margin from top and bottom

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[landscape,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[landscape,a5paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[landscape,paperheight=8.17in,paperwidth=6.32in,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\mygraphpaper{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {4,5,...,28}{
  \draw[gray] ($(current page.north west)+(0,-\i)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\i)$);}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
  angle=0,
  contents=\mygraphpaper,
  color=black,
  scale=1,
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
$\,$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can just use length with units in a coordinate. You don't have to use the *XYZ* coordinate system (and you can change that, too). So do you want a horizontal line every 1cm but not for the whole page but only for the text area?

Comment: hi, how would the for loop syntax works on that?

I want horizontal lines every 1cm starting from the most left of the page to the most right, but give blank 'x' cm from top  and x cm  from bottom.

Comment: I think most of my problem would be, involving the arithmetic using pre-defined length in Tex. Like I wonder if I can just do something like replacing 28 on the loop to \i*\paperheight-\j, or use while-loop , etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two parameters where `#1` stands for the distance between the first horizontal line to the top of the page and `#2` for the minimum distance to the bottom you can use define `\mygraphpaper` as such

```
\newcommand*\mygraphpaper[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \foreach[parse=true] \i in {0,...,(\paperheight-(#1)-(#2))/1cm}{
  \draw[gray] ([yshift={-\i cm-(#1)}]current page.north west) -- ++(right:\paperwidth);}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Note that I've used `rememer picture` and `overlay` so that the special `current page` node gets recognized correctly and we don't have to deal with whereever `background` decides to place this content.

Note however, that the `everypage` package that is used by `everypage` is deprecated.

---

With a LaTeX version of the past two years, you can (should) use the `shipout/background` hook which acts as a `picture` that has its origin at the top left corner of the page. Since you're only drawing horizontal lines, you can just draw it that way without having to use PGF/TikZ

The same math as before gets us the needed number of iterations for `\multiput`.

### Code (TikZ + `background`/`everypage`)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[landscape,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[landscape,a5paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[landscape,paperheight=8.17in,paperwidth=6.32in,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand*\mygraphpaper[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \foreach[parse=true] \i in {0,...,(\paperheight-(#1)-(#2))/1cm}{
  \draw[gray] ([yshift={-\i cm-(#1)}]current page.north west) -- ++(right:\paperwidth);}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
  angle=0,
  contents=\mygraphpaper{3.5cm}{5cm},
  color=black,
  scale=1,
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
$\,$
\end{document}
```

### Code (`shipout/background` + `picture`)

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[landscape,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[landscape,a5paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[landscape,paperheight=8.17in,paperwidth=6.32in,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*\mygraphpaper[2]{%
  \color{gray}
  \setlength\unitlength{1cm}
  \linethickness{.4pt}
  \multiput(0,-#1)(0,-1){\fpeval{1+trunc((\paperheight-#1cm-#2cm)/1cm,0)}}{%
    \line(1,0){\paperwidth}
  }
}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\mygraphpaper{3.5}{5}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
$\,$
\end{document}
```

Comment: A combination of TikZ (or better PGF) and the `shipout/background` is possible, of course, but I haven't put much thought into it since `picture` is all that is needed for horizontal lines.

Comment: The first code works without 'remember picture,overlay' , with them the lines are not properly located (I'm not sure why). I think I get how the first code works. Thanks!

Comment: The first code works every twice compile, it's possibly needed the aux files

Comment: Yes, [`remember picture` uses the `aux` file](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.13.1). If you don't use it, the lines are offset to the bottom (one inch because that's how that hook worked. You probably ran the second code with the aux file from the first code which doesn't recognize the PGF/TikZ macros in the aux file anymore. One could implement a TikZ solution without `remember picture` (since we know where it will be placed).

Comment: @Ajat Since `background` uses TikZ in the background I worry about interference and since it uses deprecated packages I wouldn't pursue a solution with it anyway. If you insist on a TikZ solution, I could take a closer look into using TikZ with `shipout/background`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `grid` operation from TikZ (the negative (or zero) value for `xstep` will remove the vertical lines, so you just get your horizontal rules):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[landscape,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[landscape,a5paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[landscape,paperheight=8.17in,paperwidth=6.32in,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\mygraphpaper{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \draw[ystep=1cm, xstep=-1cm, gray] ([yshift=-2cm]current page.north west) grid ([yshift=2cm]current page.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
  angle=0,
  contents=\mygraphpaper,
  color=black,
  scale=1,
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
$\,$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I always forget about the built-in loop of `grid` … By the way, a step value of `0(pt)` already triggers the non-drawing. (It checks for `>0.01pt`.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel updated, thanks for your comment!

Comment: thank you for the neat answer! this fit nicely since I also want to make a squared graphpaper.

Comment: @Ajat You're welcome!